# Install gstreamer version 0.10 in Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: apt, ssh, launchpad, gstreamer

So previously I was using Fedora 24, and I had a thing set up where I was using `gstreamer`, `ssh`, and `v4l2loopback` to mirror my laptop's screen to another computer. Essentially I set up a dummy video interface which mirrored my screen, and from the client computer I would call,

```
gst-launch-0.10 v4l2src device=/dev/video1 ! xvimagesink
```

over an ssh session with X11 forwarding enabled, and it would mirror the screen. Recently I switched to Ubuntu (MATE) 17.04, and I set up the whole chain, and I can successfully run the command to view the stream from the server computer itself, but when I try to call it over ssh it fails with the error,

```
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0: Failed to allocate a buffer.
```

I've done some Googling around, and as far as I can tell, others have had a similar problem when switching from `gstreamer 0.10` to `gstreamer 1.0`, and the only difference between my previous (working) setup and my new setup is that I had 0.10 installed on Fedora and 1.0 installed on Ubuntu. So my question is not so much how to resolve this error, as, is it possible to install `gstreamer 0.10` in Ubuntu 17.04? I'm fairly new to Ubuntu and Debian based systems in general, and I see that `gstreamer 0.10` has a Launchpad page, but I can't figure out if that means I can actually install it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's probably going to be easier to port this process to GST 1.x or use a different screen sharing or remote desktop method altogether than to install GST 0.10 in Ubuntu 17.04.

Comment: I had the same inclination, but I'm pretty unfamiliar with gstreamer, and in researching it I haven't been able to figure out what the specific cause of this error is, or even really what it means. A quick fix using gstreamer 1.0 would be preferable, but since the only solution I've been able to find by looking at other forums is to downgrade, that's what I'm trying to do.

Comment: "Downgrading" would be disastrous. Installing GST 0.10 alongside GST 1.x would be better; that's how it's done in Trusty anyway. I agree that porting the commands to GST 1.x may be difficult because Gnome's documentation tends to be anywhere between non-existent, outdated or terrible.

Comment: Alright cool, thanks for the clarification. Do you know how I could go about doing that, though?